# Timer and Processing Issues in C#

Tags: c#, service, timer

I have a service that processes files.  Sometimes they process very quickly and sometimes they take a very long time.  I can't control the process that sends the files to me.  The are randomly dropped on me throughout the day and night.  When I use the timer, it seems like the "ProcessFiles" method is abandoned whereever it is when the time has elapsed and ProcessFiles is called again.  Since the files contain sensitive information, they can't sit on the server for a long time so I can't set the timer for any longer than 5 minutes and, still, at 5 minutes, the process sometimes interrupts itself.  As a result, I have partially processed files.  I would appreciate any thoughts and input on this quandary.

```
    System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    // As the files come in, massage them and encrypt them

    public const string InPath = @"c:\input";
    public const string OutPath = @"\c:\output";

    public FileMassaging()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public EventLog MyEventLog = new EventLog();
    public string sSource = "FileMassaging";
    public string sLog = "FileMassaging";

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // Create the source, if it does not already exist.
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sSource))
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource, sLog);

        // set up the service
        ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING;
        serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 100000;
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);

        // set up the service

        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
        _timer.Interval = 5000;
        _timer.Start();


        // Update the service state to Running.
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
    }


    public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        ProcessFiles();
    }


      public void ProcessFiles()
    {
            string[] originalFiles = Directory.GetFiles(InPath + @"\", "*.txt");
            foreach (string fileName in originalFiles)
            {
                 // Check and process the file
                 CheckFile(InPath, OutPath, fileName);
            } 

    }

    public void CheckFile(string InPath,Outpath, fileName)

      {
       // for example only -- actual file processing is much longer
       // 
       string infile = InPath+fileName;
       string outfile= OutPath+fileName;
       File.Move(infile,outfile,true);
      }
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand the requirement of the timer.  Why not just use a Folder Watcher and when the file is created do what you need to do and then move the file. Or control the process that drops the file there to encrypt?

Comment: I guess the best way I see it is why wait for the timer, just move upon entering.  Then again if you're moving why not just put it the place you're moving too.

Comment: I'll edit my question but files from other places get randomly dropped in our folders and we have to massage and encrypt them.  The file watcher wasn't reliable enough.  If a bunch of files came at the same time, it wouldn't alert me in a way that I could process all of them so files would get missed.

Comment: With respect to [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787116/reporting-progress-using-writetoserverasync), if you delete the question, no one can post a comment on it, to help you improve it or provide additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing and extensiblity I would recommend a different overall structure.

First let's seperate out this work into classes where it makes sense. Lets start with a class called FolderWatcher:

```
public class FolderWatcher
    {
        private readonly string _inPath;
        private readonly string _outPath;

        public bool CurrentlyRunning { get; set; }

        public FolderWatcher(string inPath, string outPath)
        {
            _inPath = inPath;
            _outPath = outPath;
        }

        public void TryProcessFiles(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.CurrentlyRunning = true;
                ProcessFiles(sender, e);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.CurrentlyRunning = false;
            }
        }

        public void ProcessFiles(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            string[] originalFiles = GetFilesInDirectory();
            foreach (var originalFile in originalFiles)
            {
                CheckFile(originalFile);
            }
        }

        // Internal/Virtual so that this can mocked in unit testing.
        internal virtual string[] GetFilesInDirectory()
        {
            return Directory.GetFiles(_inPath + @"\", "*.txt");
        }

        // Internal/Virtual so that this can mocked in unit testing.
        internal virtual void CheckFile(string fileName)
        {
            string infile = $"{_inPath}{fileName}";
            string outfile = $"{_outPath}{fileName}";
            File.Move(infile, outfile);
        }

    }
```

This class has a single responsibility, to move files in response to an event.

Next let's build a class to wrap the FolderWatcher class that handles the timer functionality:

```
    public class TimedFolderWatcher
    {
        private readonly FolderWatcher _folderWatcher;
        private readonly Timer _timer;

        public TimedFolderWatcher(FolderWatcher folderWatcher)
        {
            _folderWatcher = folderWatcher;
            InitTimer();
        }

        private void InitTimer()
        {
            _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.ProcessFiles);
            _timer.Interval = 5000;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void ProcessFiles(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _folderWatcher.TryProcessFiles(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

This class also has a single responsibility to call the ProcessFiles method every 5000 milliseconds.

Lastly we can init and call these classes this way:

```
var fileMassageService = new TimedFolderWatcher(new FolderWatcher(@"c:\input", @"c:\output"));
```

This approach lends itself to testing and follows the best practices of Dependency Injection which will allow you to use an IOC framework in the future if you need to.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look at this in detail and see if I can make this work.

Comment: Hi P Roe - Thank you for your thoughtful comments.  This is a much better approach.  Would I still not have the same problem of the service stopping in the middle of the CheckFiles method and going directly to _folderWatcher.ProcessFiles?

Comment: My problem turned out to be that there was a bug in the code and the service was ignoring it.  I was able to find it after restructuring my code as you suggested so I'm going to mark this as answered.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN Page on Timers try this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
_timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5);
_timer.Elapsed += OnTimer;
_timer.AutoReset = true;
// _timer.Start();
_timer.Enable = true;

private static void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args) { ProcessFiles(); }
```